# Can I automate the process of creating a new spreadsheet in Google Sheets from a CSV with a pre-written Apps Script to be added to the Script Editor?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a Python program that takes in a handful of daily-downloaded CSV's, and the idea is to have each spreadsheet automatically, and separately uploaded to Google Sheets with new spreadsheets created from these CSV's. Also, I need each newly created spreadsheet to have an Apps Script uploaded to it. 
Everything I've seen thus far is how to perform actions on existing spreadsheets and not how to generate a new one from a file. And I haven't seen whether or not Google allows scripts to be programmatically added rather than manually added (last one being from several years ago).

Note: Combining the daily CSV's isn't possible since the client needs each spreadsheet to be sent to different recipients.

Comment: [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python). [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python).

Comment: Can you provide your current script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0):

**Goal**

- You download daily a certain amount of CSVs and want to convert them to Google Spreadsheets
- You want to attach to each of the created spreadsheets an Apps Script file

**Workflow**

There are several possibilities to realize this functionality, in order to perform the process automatically on trigger, you can use Apps Script as described below:

- To implement a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that automatically looks for newly downloaded CSV files in specified intervals (e.g. on daily basis), write a program with Apps Script, rather than with Python
- [Enable the Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
- Write a function to [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) all files of interest, whereby parameters like e.g. modification date, mime type and folder can be specified with the query string [q](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)
- Loop through the found CSV files and for each [create a new spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) and attach to it an empty [Apps Script file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/create) and [update its contents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/update)
  +[Parse the Csv file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter) and insert it into the newly created spreadsheet e.g. with [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) with the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)
- To use the Apps Script API within your Apps Script program, you can use the [URLFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- For this, associate you Apps Script project under Resources-> Cloud Platform project with a [Standard GCP Project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects) and in the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), [enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/enabled?) the  Apps Script API.

Below is a sample function that creates a new Spreadsheet with an Apps Script file and automatically writes content into this file:

```
function createSpreadsheetwithScript() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.create('myCSV');
  var id=ss.getId();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects";
  var payload = {
    "title": "myAutoCreatedScript",
    "parentId": id
  }
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
     },
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var scriptId=JSON.parse(response).scriptId;
  var url2="https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"+scriptId+"/content";
 //test content 
  var source="function myFunction() {\n var x=1;\n}";
  var JSONsource="{\"timeZone\":\"America/New_York\",\"exceptionLogging\":\"STACKDRIVER\"}";  
   var payload2 = {
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "this is the gs. file",
      "type": "SERVER_JS",
      "source": source
    },
    {
      "name": "appsscript",
      "type": "JSON",
      "source": JSONsource,
   "updateTime":"2018-03-04T19:49:08.871Z",
    "functionSet":{
      "values":[{"name":"myFunction"}]}
    }
  ]
}

var options2 = {
  "headers": {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
   }, 
  "contentType": "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json",
  "method" : "PUT", 
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload2)
  }
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,options2); 
}
```

Make sure to update the contents of the [appsscript.json file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) with the necessary authorization scopes:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp"]
}
```